# How in Inno setup add procedure created folder paths to uninstall?

Tags: inno-setup, symlink, pascalscript

My procedure reads folders names from an source location. And creates an eponymous folder in the destination. Folders every time is different that is why I can't create folders in `[Dirs]` section. I don't know what names will be there. After that folders must be replaced with symlinks.

But I want the newly created folders (symlinks) to be uninstallable. How I can "register" this folder paths for later uninstall?

Here is my procedure

```pascal
procedure CreateSymForPath(sor_pth: string; des_pth: string; isfolder: Boolean);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  RootPath: string;
  Path: string;
  LinkNfo: SYMLINK_INFO;
begin
  RootPath := ExpandConstant(sor_pth);

  if FindFirst(RootPath + '\*', FindRec) then
  begin
    repeat    
      if ((FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) <> 0) and
         (FindRec.Name <> '.') and
         (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
      begin
        Path := RootPath + '\' + FindRec.Name;

        CreateDir(ExpandConstant(des_pth +FindRec.Name));

        Log(ExpandConstant(des_pth + '\'  + FindRec.Name));
        Log(ExpandConstant('{src}' + '\' + sor_pth + FindRec.Name));

        LinkNfo.name := ExpandConstant(des_pth + '\' + FindRec.Name);
        LinkNfo.target := ExpandConstant('{src}' + '\' + sor_pth + FindRec.Name); 
        LinkNfo.create_dir := isfolder;
        LinkNfo.relative := false;
           
        ReplaceWithSymlink(LinkNfo)
      end;
    until not FindNext(FindRec);
  end;
end;
```

I tried to create a function in the [dirs] section that will recursively return paths, but I have no experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not have an API for "registering to uninstall". If you create something programmatically, you need to uninstall it programmatically too.

Use uninstaller event function [`CurUninstallStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged).